# Jquery recursive checked

Tags: jquery, recursion, checkbox

I have these checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" id-mod="1" name="read[]" />
<input type="checkbox" id-mod="4" parent="1" name="read[]" />
<input type="checkbox" id-mod="10" parent="4" name="read[]" />
<input type="checkbox" id-mod="60" parent="10" name="read[]" />
```

when checking an entry containing the attribute "parent" should automatically checked input containing the attribute "id-mod" of the same value.

Use the following function:

```
$("input:checkbox[parent]").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var parent = $(this).attr('parent');
        $("input:checkbox[id-mod='"+parent+"']").prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

For example, when check input with the attribute **parent="10"**, it also checked the input with the attribute **id-mod="10"**, but I need this it in turn  get the same event with the attribute **parent="4"** and successively...  How do I get this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try matching their attribute as

```
// run the selector and then..
var parent = $(this).attr('parent');//get parent value
$(this).parent().find('input[id-mod=' + parent + ']').prop('checked', true);
```

Then find the input from the parent element, (or if you have a class or id for the form you can use that too) and after finding update its property to checked.

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/YFXKL/ here is a fiddle for this! :)

Comment: sorry not found. Do you need to parent() function?, also, I need this to activate only when the box is checked.

Comment: No, you donot need parent. You can change the usage and the code, the `parent` is just a variable, if you mean the method (`parent()`) then you will use it if you are having multiple forms, otherwise no!

Comment: To run the code, when it is checked, use `prop('checked', true);`

Comment: @csotelo, now try it! I had a mistake in the code, you can try it now :)

Comment: The problem is the parent function. Because climbing a level where no inputs. Each checkbox is in different levels of a table and varies the number of parents. I tried with closest().find() but nothing happens. I want to activate all the boxes without depending on what level they are. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Create an function which takes an id to check. The function checks if it has an parent. If an parent is found it will call the same function again with that id.

This can however easily become an infinite loop. And your browser will not respond.